# method to interate over specific objects in a model

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a Backbone parent model/view that contains a bunch of info like:

```
this.id;
this.title;
this.department;
this.country;
this.zipcode;
```

But it also contains different people like this:

```
this.president {memberName: "Joe"};
this.vicePresident {memberName: "Jill"};
this.underwriter {memberName: "Bob"};
this.sponser {memberName: "Yoda"};
this.coSponser {memberName: "Susan"};
this.owner {memberName: "Alice"};
this.informationManger {memberName: "Pascal"};
```

The parent view needs to instantiate a child view that displays each member in it's own text field like:

```
 <input type="text" class="{{ memberType }}" value="{{ memberName }}">
```

So it would like like:

```
 <input type="text" class="president" value="Joe" />
 <input type="text" class="vicePresident" value="Jill" />
 etc...
```

I thought about using "***jQuery.each()***" to move through the model, but that would put everything into an  element.

I ended up with something like:

```
this.model.each(this.renderEachMember, this);
```

But like I said, that would interate over each object in the model and doesn't discriminate.

I just need the people to go into their own input element.

So my question is, how can I interate over the model in the parent view, pick out only the people, and then write each person to it's own child view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `this.president` returns an object and `this.id`, etc. do not.  What if you iterated through the model and checked for the presence of the key `memberName`?

Either that, or blacklist the keys you don't want and use: `_.omit(object, *keys)` (see http://underscorejs.org/#omit ).  `_` would thereby be replaced with your `this.model`, in that case.

Here's their _ example:

```
_.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'userid');
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}
_.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, function(value, key, object) {
  return _.isNumber(value);
});
=> {name: 'moe', userid: 'moe1'}
```

Conversely, there is also a `_.pick`: http://underscorejs.org/#pick